# Can we have multiple controllers in a Spring MVC application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Can we have multiple controllers in a Spring MVC application? If yes, can someone provide a working example to support this concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can. There's not much to provide:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

  @GetMapping("/users")
  // method etc.
}

@RestController
public class AccountController{

 @GetMapping("/accounts")
  // method etc.

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. Suppose that the input data received in the controller is huge and some heavy processing logic needs to be applied to this data, before persisting it in the database. So in this scenario, the data needs to be forwarded to some other class from controller. What kind of classes can we create here? Will it be a normal class or is there a special annotation that we can use to label such classes?

Comment: You will likely put it into a @Service class. You might want to read up on this article https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-framework , to give you a much better picture of Controllers, Services, Components and Repositories.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, flow happens in this way: Input is taken from jsp/html pages, based on the url, sent to Controller classes, then to Service-annotated classes for processing data and forwarded to Component-annotated DAO classes for persisting data and in case of any persistent related exceptions, to Repository-annotated classes. Please confirm.

Comment: The last part is off, DAOs and Repositories are the same. So you would have the \@controller delegating to \@service delegating to a \@Repository. But that has nothing to do with exceptions.